buildozer fails with "undefined reference to `PyFrame_Type'"
I am trying to use buildozer to build a .apk file to install on Android.  In one of the steps, where it is using gcc to link, the first warning is:
/usr/bin/ld: Python/traceback.o: warning: relocation against PyFrame_Type' in read-only section .text'
No .apk file is built and left in my bin directory.
I have installed everything required by buildozer.  Originally, I installed openjdk version 21.  But then I tried downgrading to version 17.  I have python 3.11.9 installed.
I am using Solus 4.5.
